# PatchValue or setValue with formGroup more formArray and formGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have the second forms. I need to fill in the fields with the date coming from the bank, a json file. In the `populateFields` method I get a parameter with the data that will be filled. But, it fills only the values ​​of `itens`, description that is inside the array, it does not execute.

Error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.form.controls.itens.value [i] .description.patchValue is not a function

I tried to use the following expression:

```
this.form.controls.itens.value[i].description.patchValue(item.description);
```

However, I get the error mentioned above.

```
 generateFormGroup(): void {
        this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
          id: [null],
          alias: ['Relatório de Despesa', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
          job: [null, [Validators.required]],
          customer: [{ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.required]],
          contact: [{ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.required]],
          currency: [{ value: 1, disabled: true }, [Validators.required]],
          exchangeRate: [{ value: null, disabled: true }],
          advanceValue: ['0'],
          itens: this._formBuilder.array([this.createItem()]),
        });
      }

      createItem(): any {
        return this._formBuilder.group({
          id: [null],
          product: [null, [Validators.required]],
          productIcon: [null],
          description: this._formBuilder.group({
            descriptionProduct: [null],
            origin: [null],
            km: [null],
            destination: [null],
            rental: [null],
            days: [null],
            reason: [null],
            taglist: [null]
          }),
          date: [this.today, [Validators.required]],
          value: [0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0.01)]],
          currency: [{ value: 1, disabled: true }, [Validators.required]],
          currencyAlias: [this.currency],
          receipt: [null],
          isLoading: [false],
          receiptId: [null],
          receiptExtension: [null],
        });
      }

    populateFields(data: any): void { 
 data.itens.forEach((item, i) => {
 this.form.controls.itens.value [i] .description.patchValue (item.description) // error
          }   
            this.itens = data.itens;
            this.form.controls.itens.patchValue(data.itens);

      }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this.form['controls']['itens']['controls'][index]['controls'].description.patchValue(item.description);`

**Update:**

I used the square brackets notation of accessing properties to suppress errors like `Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'`

you can read more about it on [this Github Page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6099)

This is an issue only when you have multiple levels of formcontrols. If you have something straight forward you can use the `.` notation or even the `.get()` method to access controls

```
this.form.controls.someControl.patchValue(someValue)

this.form.get('someControl').patchValue(someValue)
```

The above two do the same thing. If it's a straightforward form array, you can use the `.at()` method

Combining these and doing some type casting, you can do something like this

```
((this.form.get('controls') as FormArray).at(index) as FormGroup).get('description').patchValue(item.description);
```

Theoretically the above should work :)

Comment: Could you explain me when you use this way?

Answer (score 0):

`this.form.controls.itens.value [i]` will give you a `formGroup`. You need to access `this.form.controls.itens.value [i].controls['description'].patchValue()`.